# Finding the start date of the latest continuous streak in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

| date | cases_count |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-04-02 | 3 |
| 2023-04-03 | 0 |
| 2023-04-04 | 0 |
| 2023-04-05 | 1 |
| 2023-04-06 | 0 |
| 2023-04-07 | 0 |

**How do I write a function to find the latest *date* of continuous streaks of 0 `cases_count`?**
In the above example, the function should return `2023-04-06`.

Thank you!

I tried finding the *latest* day where `cases_count == 0` but that ignores the possibility of there being dates prior to that in a continuous streak.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the *title* of your question, you can use [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html)/[`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)/[`tail`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tail.html) :

```
#is it the continuous streak start ?
m = df["cases_count"].diff(-1).eq(0)

out = df.loc[m, "date"].tail(1).item() # or max()
#'2023-04-06'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a boolean mask:

```
import numpy as np

# boolean mask
m = df['cases_count'].eq(0) & df['cases_count'].shift().ne(0)

df.loc[np.where(m)[0][-1], 'date']

# OR

df.loc[m[::-1].idxmax(), 'date']

# Output
'2023-04-06'
```